# How to get the SUM value and Count for the column separated by semicolon

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a table as below wherein Value column has values separated by semicolon, I need 4th Column as SUM and 5th Columns as COUNT.
COUNT is the count of number separated by semicolon, ignoring the blanks

```
Number  Number_SEQ  Value
     1          A1  NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;1.5;-34.0;-34.9;6.0;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN
     2          A2  NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;-34.9;6.0;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN
```

Output ,

```
Number  Number_SEQ    SUM  COUNT
     1          A1  -73.4      4
     2          A2  -28.9      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from a little correction of your sample data (changes in sign
of some velues). In order to get the expected result, it should be:

```
   Number Number_SEQ  Value
0       1         A1  NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;1.5;-34.0;-34.9;-6.0;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN
1       2         A2  NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;-34.9;6.0;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN;NaN
```

Define the following function:

```
def process(row):
    lst = row.Value.split(';')
    lst = list(map(lambda x: float(x), filter(lambda x: x != 'NaN', lst)))
    return pd.Series([row.Number, row.Number_SEQ, sum(lst), len(lst)],
        index=['Number', 'Number_SEQ', 'SUM', 'COUNT'])
```

Then apply it as follows:

```
result = df.apply(process, axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
   Number Number_SEQ   SUM  COUNT
0       1         A1 -73.4      4
1       2         A2 -28.9      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
pd.concat((df, df['Value'].str.split(';', expand=True)
                   .astype(float).T
                   .agg(['sum','count']).T
          ), axis=1)
```